# What is 'it' in the phrase 'with future on the uncertain ground as it's'?

Tags: pronouns

[image]

The text shown in the image is:

> However, at 34 years of age and with his future in international cricket on uncertain ground as it’s, any setback is bad news for the Australian all-rounder at this late stage of his career and Watson faces a nervous wait for the results of scans. *([Source](http://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/sport/shane-watson-waits-on-injury-report-following-australias-controversial-odi-win-over-england/news-story/e3bec2b79b0d7233d0ae997c6c37aeaf))*

What is 'it' as shown in the image , clear from the title. Also it is not 'its', that should be noted well.

Comment: It should be ***its*** (possessive, therefore no comma). In this context, ***it*** refers back to ***international cricket*** (which has an uncertain future just as ***he*** does (i.e. - ***his future** and **its future*** are being compared). Either that or the writer is ignorant, since it's not grammatical to contract ***is*** if what he means is *with his future as uncertain **as it is***.

Comment: In either case, this sentence is plain horrible to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Huh?  "...with his future in international cricket on uncertain ground as its" doesn't make any sense.  I suspect that the author wrote or intended "as it is", and it got "corrected" to *it's*.

Comment: In any case I might have written "on as uncertain ground as it is"... but yea, I agree with @MadWard, really terrible sentence.

Comment: @stangdon: *With my future [as] uncertain as **hers**, we decided to delay marrying*. Perfectly ordinary English, and syntactically identical to the first interpretation I put forward above - which at least has the merit of supposing the writer did actually have reasonable command of *spoken* English (the fact that possessive ***its*** has no comma is an irrelevant quirk of orthography). Do you have a problem with the *semantics* of someone asserting that ***international cricket's*** future is on uncertain ground? You can't really argue against it on *syntactic* grounds.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'll grant that you can use "its" that way.  Still, I feel like there's a bit of a difference in your sentence and the original that makes them not syntactically identical  *Hers* obviously refers to someone in another sentence, but in the original sentence, "its" would have to refer to something in the earlier prepositional phrase in the same sentence, not even to the subject of the clause.

Comment: I'm also tempted to so argue.  The first "as" in your example, @FumbleFingers, is not optional.  With it, you are comparing two futures, yours and hers.  Without it, you are judging one of your potential futures, that future in which you belong to her.  In both cases, the genitive pronouns have clear antecedents.  In OP's example and in the absence of a reflexive reference, international cricket's own future is not an available antecedent.

Comment: It's not a bad sentence at all.  The contraction should not be there, and it should read as others have suggested, "...as it *is*, ..."

Comment: "as it is" can be paraphrased "already".  This flaming bananas dish, which calls for a generous amount of saffron, is expensive as it is; setting a fifty-year-old scotch aflame puts its price through the roof.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What do you mean it got 'corrected'?Do you mean it got wrong?

Comment: @Anubhav: I never mentioned 'corrected'. But unquestionably the text you cite is incorrect. Idiomatically, uncontracted **as it is** would be normal here, but I've never heard of "style assistant" software that would change **it is** to **it's**, and I find it hard to believe *any* native speaker would accidentally write the contracted form in this context. So I think either your writer isn't even a native speaker in the first place, or we have to consider my (admittedly, more fanciful) alternative explanation. It's not an "instructive" issue though - just an unusual bit of garbage text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "as it's" is a typo for "as it is", then we can consider the "it" to be *semantically empty*.   This kind of "it" is sometimes called a *dummy* or *expletive* pronoun.

The phrase "as it is" can be used as an idiom with a meaning close to "under current circumstances" or "in this situation".   In that case, the "it" doesn't refer to anything.   The same lack of semantic value can be found in the sentence "it is raining" -- there is no "it" which rains, but the predicate still requires a subject.

Watson's future doesn't look good now.   His future will look even worse if his scan results contain bad news.

When "it is" stands as a complete clause, it should not be contracted.   The "as it's" in your example must be a typo of something.   Replacing the typo with "as it is" makes more sense than replacing it with "as its".   The idiomatic "as it is" doesn't require an antecedent, and I cannot find a suitable antecedent for "as its" in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I find "its" as a possessive pronoun here (like "mine" or "hers") hard to accept. The OED lists the pronominal use of "its" as "rare"; and I can't search for it in the corpora, because the UCREL Claws7 part-of-speech list doesn't have a category for it. ('PPGE' is "nominal possessive personal pronoun (e.g. mine, yours)", but doesn't match "its"; whereas 'APPGE' ("possessive pronoun, pre-nominal (e.g. my, your, our)") does match 'its'.

I think "it is" is a far more likely reading.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that *it's* refers to *uncertain ground*, and the meaning is:

> ...on uncertain (*as of now*) ground

or, in a more meaningful way,

> ...on currently uncertain ground